# How to order a subquery in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm working on a program that allows a user to create events, and have other users RSVP to those events. When fetching these events, I would like to be able to sort the attendees by when they have RSVP'd (both those that have accepted, and those that have declined). I store the time that a user RSVP'd in the database. These are the relevant tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE users (
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    server_id VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    role VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (username, server_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (server_id) REFERENCES servers(server_id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE events (
    server_id VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    start_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    time_zone VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(1000),
    PRIMARY KEY (server_id, title),
    FOREIGN KEY (server_id) REFERENCES servers(server_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE user_event (
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    server_id VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    attending BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    last_updated DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (username, server_id, title),
    FOREIGN KEY (server_id, title) REFERENCES events(server_id, title)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (server_id, username) REFERENCES users(server_id, username)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Previous to wanting to sort by when a user RSVP'd, I was using this query and it was working great.

```
SELECT title, description, start_time, time_zone, (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT username)
            FROM user_event
            WHERE user_event.server_id = %s
            AND user_event.title = %s
            AND user_event.attending = 1)
            AS accepted, (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT username)
            FROM user_event
            WHERE user_event.server_id = %s
            AND user_event.title = %s
            AND user_event.attending = 0)
            AS declined
          FROM events
          WHERE server_id = %s
          AND title = %s;
```

However, adding an `ORDER BY last updated` clause to the two nested SELECT statements does not seem to have any effect. Is this a limitation of MySQL, or is there still a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you have the same `server_id` in `user_event` referencing both `events` (combined with title) and users (combined with username)?  Seems like you would end up with multiple records in `users` and/or `events` for a single user or single event, just to cross match them with their `user_event` records.  I know this does not address your question, but your table structure seems very suspect.

Comment: Do you want order in the grouped column, or do you want to order the whole result by the user_event.last_updated column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `ORDER BY` inside `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT title, description, start_time, time_zone, (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT username ORDER BY last updated)
            FROM user_event
            WHERE user_event.server_id = %s
            AND user_event.title = %s
            AND user_event.attending = 1)
            AS accepted, (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT username ORDER BY last updated)
            FROM user_event
            WHERE user_event.server_id = %s
            AND user_event.title = %s
            AND user_event.attending = 0)
            AS declined
          FROM events
          WHERE server_id = %s
          AND title = %s;
```

Comment: You're a saint! Thank you so much :)